# How to use configuration management to configure Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, ansible

I am looking for a way to add/remove/update Jenkins master environment variables using some way of configuration management.

If this can be done with Ansible even better.

Please note that I would like to avoid patching the config.xml file manually, especially because this would risk to create issues and a Jenkins restart would be required and this is to be avoided whenever is possible.

In case it was not clear, I am trying to find an automation solution for altering `Manage Jenkins - Configure System - Global properties`.

Comment: Have you seen http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/list_of_all_modules.html ?

Answer (score 0):

you can configure all your Jenkins master using groovy.

I just did the same when we upgrade to Jenkins 2.

here are some links : https://pghalliday.com/jenkins/groovy/sonar/chef/configuration/management/2014/09/21/some-useful-jenkins-groovy-scripts.html

https://github.com/DotCi/jenkinsci-dotci-example/blob/master/configure-dotci.groovy

https://gist.github.com/vrivellino/97954495938e38421ba4504049fd44ea

BTW , you can install your plugins using CLI it will save you time in the future.

and you can create all your jobs using DSL , so all changes will be in github.

if you have specific question , let me know